# Im getting objectHTMLimageElement instead of the image in my list item

Tags: javascript

```
function story(){
   
   

    if(document.getElementById("area").value == "salwa"){
        var oImg = document.createElement("img");
    oImg.setAttribute('src', './images/logo.png');
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
    oImg.setAttribute('height', '1px');
    oImg.setAttribute('width', '1px');
    document.body.appendChild(oImg);
    document.getElementById("story-result").innerHTML += "<li>" + oImg + " </li>";

  
}else{
    document.getElementById("li-result").innerHTML += "<h1>" + "no results" + " </h1>";
}

}
```

Comment: You can use `outerHTML` attribute of the image to get the serialized HTML fragment, for example, `document.getElementById("story-result").innerHTML += "<li>" + oImg.outerHTML + " </li>"`. Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/poywxvB

Answer (score 1):

Is this working?

```
function story(){
if (document.getElementById("area").value == "salwa"){
document.getElementById("story-result").innerHTML = "<img src=" + "'./images/logo.png'" + "alt=" + "'na'" + "height=" + "'1px'" + "width=" + "'1px'" + ">" + "</img>";
} else {
document.getElementById("li-result").innerHTML += "<h1>" + "no results" + " </h1>";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the image *source attribute* and make it equal to the innerHTML of the element with id story-result.

You are currently using the image itself, not its `src` attribute.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("story-result").innerHTML += "<li>" + oImg.getAttribute('src') + " </li>";
```